# android map v1 signing key

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an built an application 6 months ago that uses google maps v1. Now I want to publish it in the Google Play Store
When I was working on it I  did the procedure required to obtain a key. As far I remember I used the cmd to generate a MD5 that I pasted in a site.
I have saved the file with the result which is something like that

```
letersandnumbers

This key is good for all apps signed with your certificate whose fingerprint is:
hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex:hex

Here is an example xml layout to get you started on your way to mapping glory:

              <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="letersandnumbers"
                 />
```

When I compile and run the application on my phone that is on debug mode, it works.
When I try to use the  `letersandnumbers` as a key to sign my application the result is different. The application shows only grid and not the map. 
The way I sign my application is the following:

> 1)File->export->android application
>
> 2) I select the project and use the lettersandnumber key mentioned
>   above.
>
> 3) I put the file on the SD card of the device and install it.

Am I doing something wrong?
Please help! Switching to maps v2 is not an option

UPDATE:

I managed to follow the guide Daniel writes about in the comment. However when I use the new key in the manifest and sign the app with this new Key it does not work...
I am trying to use maps version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any success using maps API v1. It is deprecated since december and you can't get new keys since march. Rework your app to use API v2.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to generate the hash key for your signed cert.  From what you explained it seems like you have added the hash for your debug key cert only which is why when your debugging the maps work.  So once again, you need to run the keytool command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

This time make sure you refer to the keystore your using to sign your app when you export it.  Then enter the new hash into the google API console -> API ACCESS -> Create new Android Key.  You'll be given a new API key that you will need to add to your maps entry in the layout.xml file you referenced above.

Comment: When I do the last step it tells me that Your input was invalid. I did all the steps like you described, only the last one fails.

Comment: So you entered the new hash from your new keystore using the "Create android Key" dialog, and thats where says invalid?

Comment: OK I managed to create the key. The problem was that I needed to give the SHA1;project.name. Now I have got the key. I took it and put it in the manifest. Then I signed the application with the new key, that google generated for me. However the map still doesn't work. any ideas ?

Comment: Make sure you are putting the new api key that you generated from your new keystore into the layout file.  Then export the app, sign it with the new keystore, install and run that apk.

Comment: I did what you say but still doesn't work. I see from the code that I have used for my class extends MapActivity. This means that I am using map version 1 right ? The key I generated works with version 1 or only version 2 ? Am I missing something  ?

Comment: The only other problem I could think of is that when you generated your api key it was for google maps v1, but was based off of your debug keystore.  Since you can no longer develop keys for Google maps v1, this whole process probably isn't working because they new api keys you are getting are only for google maps v2.  The only option I can see is to sign with your debug keystore and upload that to google play, not sure if you want to do that though.  Sorry at this point I'm out of options.